# WCF: Web Service or not?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm at the moment creating an ASP.NET web app which should call a WCF Service... The WCF Service have 2 methods:

```
Bitmap TakeScreenDump(string websiteUrl, int width, int height);
Bitmap GenerateThumbNail(Bitmap source, int width, int height);
```

The purpose of my ASP.NET web app is to let a user request a screenshot for a specific website, which the web app will hand over to the WCF Service.

Now is my question: Should I create the WCF Service as a Web service (http binding) ? or should I create it as a Console service (`net.tcp`)? My WCF Service wont be used by anyone else than me.

Whats the advantages/disadvantages of those two in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter. The service code will be exactly the same.

It's one of the most important things about WCF that the service is separate from the binding. If you think you might want to use more than one binding, then create the service as a "WCF Service Library" project. Then you can host it in a Console Application, Windows Service, or whatever, using whichever binding you like.

In fact, there's no reason you can't do both. You can host it in a Console application using one of the HTTP bindings if you like.

Comment: @John Saunders - So its just a matter of taste whether to use a Web Service in my case?

Comment: @EBB: your terminology is also an issue. It's a matter of taste and requirements as to whether the service is accessible from the web, and with what protocols. There's no reason a WCF service can't use `net.tcp` and still be accessible over the Internet (to WCF clients, at any rate). These decisions are independent of each other.

Comment: @John Saunders - Forgive my stupidness but... if net.tcp is accessible over the Internet, why use a Web Service over a Service that use net.tcp and is hosted by a Console app?

Comment: @ebb: HTTP calls (what you refer to as "web services") are typically available and accessible everywhere, since port 80 is open on most servers. Net.TCP typically uses a custom port, which requires configruation on servers and firewalls, and some admins might be very reluctant to open ports for something that's not deemed absolutely essential. So HTTP is easier since it can reach more computers.

Comment: @ebb: but again, since John so clearly pointed out: this has **no impact** on how you create and write your service code! The code is the same - whether you expose the service as a HTTP or Net.TCP endpoint. Heck: you can even expose **BOTH** endpoints from your serviec and let the clients decide what endpoint and thus binding/protocol they want to use. Ah, the beauty of WCF !

Comment: @marc_s - Thanks, that helped a lot ;) - But which would you choose if it's a service that shouldnt be available to anyone else than yourself? - Would Net.TCP be the way or are there still arguments for choosing HTTP (Web Service)?

Comment: @ebb: if you run this on a local LAN, and no one from the outside should be able to connect to it - yes, then use net.tcp - it's typically faster than http. Plus again: if you suddenly need to expose it to the outside world, just add a second, http-based endpoint to your service; that's only a config change, no code needs to be touched !

Comment: @marc_s - so I can make my WCF Service to a "Web Service" just by adding an endpoint in my service?

Comment: @ebb: YES! A WCF service has all it takes to be a "web service" and exposing it over http gives it the same reach as the "old-style" ASP.NET / ASMX web services! And you need to add that endpoint only to your service **config** - it has **no impact** on and requires **no change** in your service **code**!

Comment: @marc_s - I feel embarrassed over trying to figure out how to expose my WCF Service now... Anyway - thank you very much, I get the concept of WCF now ;=)!

Comment: @marc_s - just a last question... My WCF Service is at the moment in same assembly as the Console app thats hosts it.. Those two need to be sepearted in order to be able to change the endpoints etc. right?

Comment: @ebb: they don't need to be - technically - but it would make good sense, yes.

Comment: @ebb: I'd suggest to just start trying - create your service, expose it over net.tcp, get a client to it to work, and then try to add a second endpoint over http to the same service, and see that this works. If you have more question - this is the place to come ask them!

Comment: @marc_s - I see... Another thing that confuses me is that when I want to host my service as net.tcp in a console app, then the console app should have the app.config and the wcf service itself none. When I then want to use it as http (web service) then it needs an app.config file by itself? (I'm trying to add reference to the service in my asp.net solution) - not sure any of that made sense at all..

Comment: @ebb: you need to configure the service in the host application it lives in. In a console app, when self-hosting, that's the console app's `app.config` - if you host in IIS, it's the virtual directory's `web.config` where you service lives (the *.svc file for it)

Comment: @marc_s - Ah, I see.. so the service itself never holds the config file :) Lets say I have a WCF Service hosted by a console app using net.tcp and later I want to move it to a Web Service... how would I edit the extension to .svc? Recompile?

Comment: @ebb: if you host a service inside a console app, and you want to add a second endpoint - just add that second endpoint to the `app.config`! No change, no recompilation - NOTHING - just update the config and you're done!

Comment: @marc_s - but then its still hosted by the console app which uses the net.tcp endpoint? (am I missing something here?) - isnt a web service meant to be hosted on the web server with the file extension .svc?

Comment: @ebb: a console app using the `ServiceHost` object can host **ANY** kind of WCF endpoint - net.tcp, net.msmq, http - whatever you like. There is **NO NEED** to use IIS (and thus a .svc file) to host a http-based WCF service! You can host WCF services in IIS, if you want to (I wouldn't) - or you can self-host. Both options are almost identical (the self-hosting is actually even **more flexible** and powerful!). Just to expose a WCF service over HTTP does **NOT** require you to use IIS !

Comment: @marc_s - ah that clears up a few things :=) - But by using the ServiceHost object... Will it by default use all of the endpoints defined in my config, or do I need to make some fancy thing to have it both working with net.tcp and later http (without hardcoding it into the ServiceHost object)?

Comment: @ebb: the `ServiceHost` will use and interpret your config just fine - no magic tricks needed

Comment: @marc_s - so it will use all of the endpoints defined automatically?

Comment: @ebb: YES! Go ahead and TRY IT !

Comment: @marc_s - I will! but... I've just defined a http endpoint in my console app (host) config file... But I'm not able to right click my ASP.NET app and "Add Service Reference" - its not found?

Comment: @ebb: if you have another question - post a new question here. Provide the code and config so we can see what you have!

Comment: @ebb: if you send  me an e-mail to my address in my profile, I'll send you a sample of a console app host and show how it uses all the endpoints in the config (and how you can check that, too) ...

Comment: @marc_s: @ebb: I thought I was dreaming when the inbox said i had 27 comments to read...

Comment: @ebb: lets _do_ keep in mind this isn't a discussion forum. As you get specific questions on this subject, please ask them as separate questions. Fewer comments that way, but more answers.